# How to add a device to all docker containers

Tags: docker, sgx

To make use of SGX enclaves applications have to talk to the SGX driver which is exposed via `/dev/isgx` on the host. We execute such applications inside of Docker containers mapping `/dev/isgx` inside with the `--device` command line option.

**Is there an option to add a device (`/dev/isgx` in this case) to any container ever started by a docker engine?**

**Edit:**

Progress on my side so far:

Docker uses `containerd` & `runc` to create a containers configuration before it is started. [Docker's configuration file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#linux-configuration-file) `/etc/docker/daemon.json` has a field `runtimes` where one can provide arbitrary arguments to `runc`:

```
[...]    
"runtimes": {
    "runc": {
        "path": "runc"
    },
    "custom": {
        "path": "/usr/local/bin/my-runc-replacement",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--debug"
        ]
    }
},
[...]
```

Sadly, it seams `runc` is not consuming to many useful arguments for my means (`runc --help` and `runc spec --help` <-- creates the configuration).

I found interesting [source code](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/52454cf90807727923b375afd7d84ac8fd523959/libcontainer/configs/device_defaults.go) regarding `DefaultSimpleDevices` and `DefaultAllowedDevices` in `runc`'s codebase. The last commit to this file says 'Do not create /dev/fuse by default' which is promising, but would involve building my own `runc`. I was hoping for a generic solution via a configuration option.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

**This is not the correct answer**. Turns out, that docker's default parent cgroup already has open `devices` permissions:

```
/# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/docker/devices.list 
a *:* rwm
```

Upon container creation a new cgroup for that container is created with more restricted `devices` rules.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I think you could use cgroups to achieve what you want.
You could create a new cgroup on your host machine which allows access to `/dev/isgx` and start your docker daemon with `--cgroup-parent=<my-cgroup-name>`.
You could also set the `cgroup-parent` option in your `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.

If you have never worked with cgroups before, then it might not be trivial to setup though.
How to create a new cgroup depends on your host system, but you must use the [`devices`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v2/devices.txt) controller to whitelist specific devices for a cgroup.

E.g., one way is to use [`libcgroup`'s](http://libcg.sourceforge.net/html/index.html) `/etc/cgconfig.conf` and give read/write access to a block device for cgroup `dockerdaemon` in the following way:

```
group dockerdaemon {
  devices {
    devices.allow = b <device-major>:<device-minor> rw
  }
}
```

Here is one example on how to find out the major/minor of your block device:

```
sudo udevadm info -n /dev/isgx
```

Here are some further links that might give you more insights into the whole cgroup topic:

- [cgroups in CentOS6](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-limit-resources-using-cgroups-on-centos-6)
- [cgroups in redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch-Using_Control_Groups.html)
- [cgroups in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cgroups.html)

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I have not yet worked with cgroups. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: After looking into it I doubt cgroups can help here. It seams the docker daemon is by default running with the most permissive device cgroup there is. Only when it starts a container a new restricted cgroup is created for it. In fact `--device /dev/X` adds the devices major and minor number to the cgroup.

Comment: @fzgregor you are absolutely right. I assumed that new cgroups would inherit **ALL** the settings from its parent, but I was wrong. Thank you for the clarification! I updated the answer with your findings.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this in your `docker-compose.yaml` file (or similar for other Docker-based technologies:

```
    devices:
      - "/dev/isgx:/dev/isgx"
```